# Mimic alt + backspace in iTerm2

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to figure out how to mimic the `alt + backspace` behaviour in iTerm2.

(In a Linux virtual terminal that should delete everything before a non alpha character, I guess)

I can send a key sequence, but I don't know what to send. Any ideas how to find that?

Answer (score 11):

In Preferences > Profiles > Keys. Create a Key combination "⌥ ← Delete" and have it Send Hex Codes: 0x1B 0x08.

It will delete one word backwards using a non-alphanumeric character as delimiter.

Comment: Nice! Others were saying "0x17", but that deletes everything until the first space(backwards of course). This behaviour here is much better, at least for me 